# SOQL query error: Semi join sub-selects are not allowed with the 'OR' operator

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, soql

can someone help me achieving this using a single query.

Is it even possible??

select id,name,department,audittime from employee
where id in (select emp_nbr from organization where emp_nbr between 1 and 10)
OR name in (select name from user where name like 'A%')